# Deprecated: __autoload() is deprecated, use spl_autoload_register()

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
function __autoload($class) {
    if (strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0) {
        if (file_exists($file = APPPATH . 'core/' . $class . php)) {
            include $file;
        }
    }
}
```

> Deprecated: __autoload() is deprecated, use spl_autoload_register()
>   and Fatal error: Cannot redeclare __autoload() error in codeigniter

Comment: I don't understand the question. *This is no longer in use. Use this instead.* seems very clear. Stop using `__autoload()` and use `spl_autoload_register()`. In what way could that be stated more clearly?

Comment: First off what version of CI are you using

Comment: __autoload has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.2.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged. see http://php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php

Comment: when use sql_autoload_register(),  got error "Fatal error: Class 'Home_My_SmartPriceController' not found"

Comment: Mr. ED i use codeginiter 3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use spl\_autoload() instead of \_\_autoload()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687804/how-to-use-spl-autoload-instead-of-autoload)

Answer (score 6):

**To Add spl_autoload_register() just replace this code with your code especially in routes.php**

```
function my_autoloader($class) {
if (strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0) {
    if (file_exists($file = APPPATH . 'core/' . $class . 'php')) {
        include $file;
    }
  }
}
spl_autoload_register('my_autoloader');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I commented out old, added @Jagadish's code and it elminated that very annoying warning in my logs.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this one worked for you because i am using it

```php
function your_autoloader($class) {

if (strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0) {

    if (file_exists($file = APPPATH . 'core/' . $class . '.php')) {

        include $file;

    }
  }
}
spl_autoload_register('your_autoloader');
```

If this did not help you call my attension

Comment: Hlo r u there. i still have same issue

Comment: @SandhyaSrishti Can you send me your error report with some of the code where it is called

Comment: Thank u so much for your attention. i resolved that issue.