# Fatal error: __autoload() is no longer supported, use spl_autoload_register() PHP 8.0

Tags: php, php-8

I have a website that was created with php 5.6 and need to update to php8.0.10.

So, in this firts troble we have a function __autoload that is no longer supported.

How can a I change to spl_autoload_register?

Look my code:

```
function __autoload($className) {
    $classpath = array(
        'model/','helpers/','plugin/email/',//frontend
        '../model/','../helpers/','../plugin/email/'//backend
        );    
    $classFile = ucfirst($className) . ".php";
    $loaded = false;
    foreach ($classpath as $path) {
        if (is_readable("$path$classFile")) {
            require "$path$classFile";
            $loaded = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is [php's own example](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php?#example-3654) as replacement to `__autoload` not enough info?

Comment: Another [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50780678/deprecated-autoload-is-deprecated-use-spl-autoload-register) and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687804/how-to-use-spl-autoload-instead-of-autoload)

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/ and generate a classmap.

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother. Use composer and remove the old stuff.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap

e.g.

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": ["src/", "lib/", "Something.php"]
    }
}
```

when that's set up properly (after composer init and so on), just run this:

- composer dump

Comment: Not solved issue, thank you.